# is it necessary to create all account, person, customer to transact in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

i need to collect money from my users which are always going to be individuals, into the the main platform balance of stripe.
it is understandable to create a connect account on stripe for each individual, but then do i need to create person object to upload and verify all details regarding KYC in Account and then do i need to create a customer to make the charges?

i am not using stripe elements, and collecting data from my own forms in frontend.

Please let me know the flow i need to follow to get my users add money into the main platform balance

Comment: You only need Accounts, Individuals, Persons if you're building a platform where you will facilitate payment for other businesses. If you're only collecting money for your own business directly from Customers, then you dont need Account, Individual, Person and only need Customer. Can you say more about what you're building?

Comment: building a wallet app.. flow is users can add money from there debit/credit/bank account > the money is added to platform balnce > on users requests transfers are made to users external account defined in Account Object. So, for adding fund need to create customer and charge, and then for paying out, need to create Account, Person, etc.. so unsure if i just need to take and create all these object or i am overdoing this app

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that might be one of the types of businesses that Stripe isn't able to support. https://stripe.com/restricted-businesses